# How to save users using PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, authentication, loopbackjs, loopback

I followed up LoopBack [JWT tutorial](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Authentication-tutorial.html#3b-add-endpoints-in-usercontroller), but it didn't mention how to store credentials in a real datasource (ex. RDBM datasource)

To do that I simply created a [datasource](https://github.com/mbnoimi/multitenancy/blob/main/src/datasources/postgresql.datasource.ts) with `connector: 'postgresql'` but it didn't work because I always get this error message!

```
Request POST /signup failed with status code 500. error: relation "public.user" does not exist
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/laptop/LoopBack/multitenancy/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:357:11)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/laptop/LoopBack/multitenancy/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:186:21)
    at Parser.parse (/home/laptop/LoopBack/multitenancy/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:101:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/laptop/LoopBack/multitenancy/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
```

You can find the full source code [here](https://github.com/mbnoimi/multitenancy)

**BTW**, When I run `npm run migrate` I expect `User` table to be generated because [user.controller.ts](https://github.com/mbnoimi/multitenancy/blob/main/src/controllers/user.controller.ts#L24) contains on an extending of `User` class, but it didn't!

May you please guide me how to store credentials in RDBM datasource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the historical record; This issue has been resolved by [Diana Lau](https://loopbackio.slack.com/archives/C01177XQN8N/p1612200630168000?thread_ts=1611683417.089900&cid=C01177XQN8N) as following:

1. Create `User` & `UserCredentials` for integrating JWT

```sh
$ lb4 model User
? Please select the model base class Entity (A persisted model with an ID)
? Allow additional (free-form) properties? No
Model User will be created in src/models/user.model.ts

Let's add a property to User
Enter an empty property name when done

? Enter the property name:
   create src/models/user.model.ts
   update src/models/index.ts

Model User was/were created in src/models
```

```sh
$ lb4 model UserCredentials
? Please select the model base class Entity (A persisted model with an ID)
? Allow additional (free-form) properties? No
Model UserCredentials will be created in src/models/user-credentials.model.ts

Let's add a property to UserCredentials
Enter an empty property name when done

? Enter the property name:
   create src/models/user-credentials.model.ts
   update src/models/index.ts

Model UserCredentials was/were created in src/models
```

2. Replace `models/user.model.ts` & `models/user-credentials.model.ts` by [user.model.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/models/user.model.ts) & [user-credentials.model.ts](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/models/user-credentials.model.ts)
3. Create repositories for `User` and `UserCredentials`

```sh
$ lb4 repository
? Please select the datasource PostgresqlDatasource
? Select the model(s) you want to generate a repository for UserCredentials, User
? Please select the repository base class DefaultCrudRepository (Juggler bridge)
? Please enter the name of the ID property for UserCredentials: id
? Please enter the name of the ID property for User: id
   create src/repositories/user-credentials.repository.ts
   create src/repositories/user.repository.ts
   update src/repositories/index.ts
   update src/repositories/index.ts

Repositories UserCredentialsRepository, UserRepository was/were created in src/repositories
```

4. Run `npm run build`
5. Modify `datasources/postgresql.datasource.ts` to meet the proper PostgreSQL configurations then create a new PostgreSQL database depending on your configurations.
6. Run `npm run migrate`
7. Delete the following files:

- `models/user.model.ts`
- `models/user-credentials.model.ts`
- `repositories/user.repository.ts`
- `repositories/user-credentials.repository.ts`

8. Modify `models/index.ts` by deleting the following lines:

```
export * from './user.model';
export * from './user-credentials.model';
```

9. Modify `repositories/index.ts` by deleting the following lines:

```
export * from './user-credentials.repository';
export * from './user.repository';
```

**NOTE**: I suggested a new feature request for a better JWT integration in [this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/7081).

Comment: This seems like bad resolution. Why Auth component couldn't create user table?

Comment: @MuratErsin This is absolutely right; This is one of the reasons that forced me to drop LoopBack in favor of NestJS